# Retornando tabela vazia

Tags: sql, postgresql, return

```
create function teste( teste varchar ) returns setof record AS $$
begin

    execute teste;
    return ;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select teste ('select * from public.opcional  ');
```

Esta me retornando record sem nada como faço pra aparecer todos os dados da tabela opcional?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o seu problema? Se você quer só os dados da Tabela select * from public.opcional.

Comment: Qual o objetivo de fazer uma função pra executar um SQL?